# Redundant Object.ToString

Tags: c#, .net, performance, refactoring, tostring

I am reviewing the following code.

```
private string MakeKey(int SnapshotID, string UserName, string BrandName)
{
    return string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", SnapshotID.ToString(), UserName, BrandName);
}
```

The `SnapshotID.ToString()` redundantly calls the `ToString()` Method.
What are the potential issues that could occur? e.g. speed.

**EDIT**
I have added a test if anyone wants to refine: http://pastebin.com/gynNjwT1

```
With ToString:      0.010884
Without ToString:   0.001446

With ToString:      0.005506
Without ToString:   0.002852

With ToString:      0.001155
Without ToString:   0.009117

With ToString:      0.003210
Without ToString:   0.001546
```

Comment: But `SnapshotID` is `int`. How `SnapshotID` can be `null`?

Comment: `int` can't be `null`. `Format` will simply call `ToString` on the inputs anyway (if not null), if I recall.

Comment: In this code...no. In case Format() is used with a IFormatProvider an explicit ToString() will override it.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes i just noticed this will update

Comment: This question is not very clear... what version of .NET are we talking about? And why is speed important in this scope? Feels like sub optimizations to me.

Comment: @Jocke .NET 4.5, I'm not saying the factions of a millisecond will make a difference to my application, it was more of **does** it make a difference not how much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code...no, it's just redundant and even slightly slower because `String.Format()` will call again `ToString()` on the `string` itself.

In case `String.Format()` is used with an `IFormatProvider` an explicit `ToString()` will override it.

**Edits (from comments):** note about performance. It may be or not slower (an *useless* `ToString()` call) compared to primitive type (`int`) boxing. We should measure this but it's pretty hard to say. What's slower? A **virtual function call** or a **boxing**? Does it really matter when compared to `String.Format()` total time? It has been [already answered here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477322/boxing-and-unboxing-in-string-format-is-the-following-rationalized). IMO if it has been done as a *smart* optimization it's pretty useless.

## Performance

OP made a small test for this (see comments), just for *fun*, results on my test machine:

```
Test               Time [ms]
With ToString      0.002929
Without ToString:  0.003414
```

I rewrote test to do not use threads (because it'll add more variables, cores may differ and OS will load them dynamically). With this (over simple!) test code (derived from OP test):

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int x = 0; x < Count; x++)
{
    _temp = MakeKeyToString(1, "Ashley", "MyBrand");
}
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan test = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I get that `ToString()` version is faster (for `Count = 1000000`) in average around 10/20 nanoseconds. IMO to measure something so small we need a much better test environment and a more professional approach. Changing his code for `String.Format()` to use `IFormatProvider`:

```
string MakeKeyToString(int SnapshotID, string UserName, string BrandName)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0}:{1}:{2}", SnapshotID.ToString(), UserName, BrandName);
}
```

Change everything again: without `ToString()` is faster for 200 nanoseconds. Again too small to measure in this way.

### Conclusions

You can't even start to consider this an optimization, too many factors will play around that and it's so small that will go unnoticed compared to total `String.Format()` time. What's worse it may introduce subtle bugs if you'll change `String.Format()` to use an `IFormatProvider`because it'll make you stop and think "Why this? There should be a culture-related reason. Maybe..." when in reality...(probably) there is not.

Comment: Would it be slower than the overhead of boxing the `int`?

Comment: @Lukazoid to be sure we should measure it but boxing _should_ be pretty fast (even if second ToString() call may be optimized away by jitter). BTW they're both (boxing and double ToString()) so small (compared to Format() itself that it's hard to speak about performance here). If it has been done as a _smart_ optimization then IMO they failed

Comment: I agree entirely, just trying to put it out there as a possible justification.

Comment: you maybe be interested to see the pastebin its very ruff and ready and could be improved http://pastebin.com/gynNjwT1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477322/boxing-and-unboxing-in-string-format-is-the-following-rationalized

Comment: @Adriano See my results in Question, its a little weird?

Comment: @AshleyMedway Not really, in average "without ToString" seems slightly faster but (if each tuple is a different run) results are pretty unstable (as we may expect for a test where _measured_ code is so little and fast). Too many factors will play with this, IMO to make a reliable test is pretty hard.

Comment: @AshleyMedway rewriting test to be serial (no threads involved because CPU cores may be different and OS may use them for different tasks) I get ToString() is faster - in average for 1000000 trials - of 10/20 nanosecods. I think it's near limit of what we can measure without a professional approach.

Comment: one thing to remember is that the first call will always be the slowest as it needs to JIT etc... but calls thereafter will be "normal"

Comment: @Ahmedilyas yes, that's why I used 1000000  repetitions.

Comment: These performance tests do not take the GC into account; the overhead of the boxing will result in many more heap allocations which will need to be GC'ed. However I think we can all see that this is unnecessary micro-optimization.

Comment: @Lukazoid absolutely right, I didn't think about GC but for real world application it'll play its role!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, by calling `Int32.ToString()` you are avoiding the overhead of boxing your `int` into an `Object`.

However the overhead of calling `.ToString()`, then having `String.Format` call `.ToString()` on that may outweight the overhead of the boxing. And all of it is negligible in respect to `String.Format`.

Comment: And doesn't the string be boxed into an object?

Answer (score -1):

Nope, The code is redundant and stop. Also `SnapshotID` cannot be null since it is an integer and not a nullable integer (`int?`). In this case the `ToString` method will be called twice I think (one explicitly and one on the result of the first call) so maybe some performance differences can be faced.